# Dropdown / Select Box Navigation with JavaScript ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to ask quick question, i want to make a select drop down that when i choose one of the options the values of the other select drop down change ...

let's say i have select drop down called model that has the following

```
- Acura
- Aston martin
- Audi
```

I want when i choose (let's say ) Audi, in the type select drop down i find Audi type's only

```
- A3
- A5
- A4
```

I don't want to use AJAX calls, i just want to use javascript or jquery to filter the data

thanks guys

Comment: This has been asked so many times. Please search for similar questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Shomz said,

Assuming the dropdowns look like this:

```
    <!-- First dropdown. Make of car -->
    <select name='Manufactor' id='make'>
        <option value='null'>Select a Make</option>
        <option value='Audi'>Audi</option>
        <option value='BMW'>BMW</option>
        <option value='Volvo'>Volvo</option>
    </select>

    <br />

    <!-- Second dropdown. Model of car -->
    <select name='Model' id='model'>
    </select>
```

The javascript would look like this:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>

    var model = ['','audi','bmw','volvo']; //Set makes
    model[1] = ['A3', 'A5', 'A4']; // Set Audi models
    model[2] = ['M3', 'M5', 'M6']; // Set BMW models
    model[3] = ['C30', 'C70'];     // Set Volvo models

    var test = model[1][1];

    function setModel(index) {
        var modelDropdown = document.getElementById('model');
        modelDropdown.options.length = null;
        for(var i = 0; i < model[index].length; i++) {
            modelDropdown.options[i] = new Option(model[index][i]);
        }
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        var makeDropdown = document.getElementById('make');
        makeDropdown.onchange = function() {
            setModel(this.selectedIndex);
        }
    }

    </script>
```

Notice that the Models start at index 1 and not 0, because the first option is a blank Select Model option.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX calls would still be the best solution, but if you don't want to use them, you can always manually create arrays for each of the main options, make an onchange event on the select element which would call the selected array and create another dropdown based on the elements of that array. Hope I didn't make it sound to complicated, since it isn't.

Here's a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/b5hKv/) how to extract values with jQuery.